# Get name from snd_kcontrol - Linux kernel sound driver

Tags: linux-kernel

I declare something like this:

```c
SOC_SINGLE_EXT("EXAMPLE_NAME", SND_SOC_NOPM, 0, 1, 0, 
example_get, example_put),
```

with:

```c
static int example_get(struct snd_kcontrol *kcontrol,
               struct snd_ctl_elem_value *ucontrol)
{
     struct snd_soc_component *component = snd_soc_kcontrol_component(kcontrol);
     struct struct_priv *my_struct = snd_soc_component_get_drvdata(component);

     return 0;
}
```

How do I fetch the name `EXAMPLE_NAME` in `example_get`? I looked through the `snd_kcontrol` struct and the `snd_soc_component` one too, but `snd_kcontrol` doesn't seem to have a name and `snd_soc_component->name` isn't what I want.

Anyone idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since I figured out the answer and thought it might be useful to others.

Using `kcontrol->id.name` is what I needed. This returns `EXAMPLE_NAME` in my example case, which is what I was looking for.